# Como obter estrutura da hierarquia de um componente delphi?

Tags: delphi, exceção

Pessoal estou tentando refinar meu log de erros e me surgiu uma ideia.

Usando um componente `ApplicationEvents`

Tenho uma rotina que grava o log de erro, nele eu pego o erro no `E.Message`, e o componente Sender que gerou o erro, até ai beleza, acontece que as vezes um `Objeto` não tem a propriedade Name e sim ClasseName, neste caso fica dificil identificar de onde partiu o erro, pra melhorar eu capturo o Form que estiver Ativo com "`Screen.ActiveControl.UnitName`", mas as vezes o formulario ativo não é quem gerou o erro mas sim um que esta sendo criado por ele... nesse caso eu teria que pegar o Componente que gerou o erro e ir subindo a hierarquia, assim eu saberia qual percurso devo fazer pra simular o erro no desenvolvimento.

Também tem uma função acoplada a essa rotina que captura a tela no momento do erro, mas as vezes o delay que existe não captura exatamente onde o mouse estava, pois pode ser em um menu que ja fechou.

Ou seja, em resumo preciso percorrer a hierarquia de um Objeto, como posso fazer isso?

Complementando porque preciso da hierarquia, porque as vezes um componente esta dentro de um `Panel->TabSheet->PageControl->Panel->Form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível retornar esta hierarquia utilizando o [parent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Parent.html) do componente, fazendo um loop recursivo até chegar no Form.

Ex, um botão, dentro de um panel em um form:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

function RetornaListaDeParents(aParent: TComponent; aLista: TList<TComponent>): TComponent;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  if aParent <> nil then
  begin
    aLista.Add(aParent);

    if aParent.GetParentComponent <> nil then
      Result:= RetornaListaDeParents(aParent.GetParentComponent, aLista)
    else
      Result:= aParent;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vLista: TList<TComponent>;
  item: TComponent;
begin
  vLista := TList<TComponent>.Create;
  try
    RetornaListaDeParents(button1, vLista);
    for item in vLista do
    begin
      showmessage(item.Name);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vLista);
  end;
end;
```

Retorno na lista: botão, painel, form.

Comment: Hum interessante... sabe me dizer se essa função funcionaria com componentes não visuais? Exemplo, o erro é em um Field de uma Query, então a hierarquia seria: Field->Query->Form, ou seja o componente está num form pois como não é TWinControl.

Comment: @Marcelo, editei a resposta agora. Abaixei um pouco mais na herança, agora utilizando o TComponent e retornando o parent pelo método GetParentComponent, desta maneira também funciona para os componentes não visuais.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo